# How can I use Python to edit a cell in several excel workbooks?

Tags: python, openpyxl

So i have the same excel workbook in several different different folders i.e. for each hotel I have a file and in that file there's an excel workbook. Now, I need to go in each file and change the contents of the cell 'B2' in worksheet "Set Up" to the hotel name (which is referred to as hotelname in my code). I try to run the code below but it gives me the error "C:\Python34\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py:319: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed" and it doesn't change anything in my excel files?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

log = 'G:\Data\Hotels\hotelnames.txt'  ##text file with a list of the hotel names 
file = open(log, 'r')
hotelnames = []
line = file.readlines()
for a in line:
    hotelnames.append(a.rstrip('\n'))

for hotel in hotelnames:
    wb = load_workbook("G:\\Data\\Hotels\\"+hotel+"\\"+hotel+" - Meetings\\"+hotel+"_Action_Log.xlsx", data_only = True)
    ws = wb["Set Up"]
    ws['B2'] = hotel  ### I want this cell to to have that particular hotel name
    wb.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be *calling* the method `wb.save`, not just referencing it. Do that by adding some parentheses and pass the file name to save the file to:

```
wb.save(filename)
```

`wb.save` only references the save method, but does not call it.

---

Also processing of the input file can be greatly simplified by iterating directly over the file object:

```
import os.path

with open(log) as f:
    file_spec = os.path.join(r"G:\Data\Hotels", '{0}', '{0} - Meetings', '{0}_Action_Log.xlsx'
    for hotel in f:
        hotel = hotel.rstrip('\n')    # probably hotel.rstrip() is sufficient
        wb = load_workbook(file_spec.format(hotel), data_only = True)
        ws = wb["Set Up"]
        ws['B2'] = hotel
        wb.save(file_spec.format(hotel))    # careful, this overwrites the original file, it would be safer to save it to a new file.
```

Comment: I now get the error TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename' so I tried adding the filename inside the paranathesis (hotel+"_Action_Log.xlsx") but still no luck; Data Validation extension is not supported and will be remov

Comment: It's a warning.

Comment: So the code should work, it does for me with openpyxl (2.5.0). What version of `openpyxl` is being used?

Comment: I'm not sure which version I'm using, how do I check?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: `print(openpyxl.__version__)`

Comment: now I'm getting "NameError: name 'openpyxl' is not defined".. could this be the root of my problems? I don't know much about python and packages so maybe i downloaded it incorrectly

Comment: You need to import the module first: `import openpyxl; print(openpyxl.__version__)`

Comment: Thanks, mine is also 2.5.0

Comment: Can you share the file (remove private info first), or create a small sample file the exhibits the problem?

Comment: https://files.fm/f/68w5qkvk     so the file is called hotelname_Action_Log.xlsx therefore in this case I need cell B2 to become "hotelname"

Comment: Using your file I get the data validation warning, but saving back to file with `wb.save(filename)` works for me. The version is the same, but I am using Linux. Try performing the same operations in an interactive Python terminal and see if that works. If it does then you will need to look at your code, perhaps the file is not being saved where you think it is?